# vs-mda-remote build fails when solution name is "www"

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I setup a new project in VS using the "Blank App (Apache cordova)" template.  When trying to build the app for IOS using vs-mda-remote on the Mac the build fails.  The console output is as follows:

```
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.0.0&cfg=debug
{ 'accept-language': 'en-US',
  host: 'michaels-mac.local:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }
New build request submitted for cordovaVersion: 4.0.0; buildCommand: build; configuration: debug
Build will be executed under: /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427
Saving build request payload to : /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427
Saved upload to /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/upload_13427.tgz
POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.0.0&cfg=debug 202 15ms - 445b
Extracting /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/upload_13427.tgz to /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp...
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp. Requesting build.
Taking 13427 as current build
Building cordova app www at appDir /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp
Opened build log file /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/build.log
GET /build/tasks/13427 200 2ms - 520b
Done building 13427 : error BuildFailedWithError [ '/Users/mike/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1' ]
Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue.
```

The contents of the "build.log" file is as follows:

```
Thu Mar 05 2015 11:47:30 GMT-0800 (PST) Begin building Cordova app at /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp
adding ios platform...
Creating ios project...
Running command: /Users/mike/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create --cli /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp/platforms/ios io.cordova.www www
mv: rename /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/www/__PROJECT_NAME__-Info.plist to /Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/www/www-Info.plist: No such file or directory
Command finished with error code 1: /Users/mike/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create --cli,/Users/mike/remote-builds/builds/13427/cordovaApp/platforms/ios,io.cordova.www,www
Thu Mar 05 2015 11:47:31 GMT-0800 (PST) Failed to build app for buildNumber: 13427: /Users/mike/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1
Thu Mar 05 2015 11:47:31 GMT-0800 (PST) Finished building Cordova app
```

This problem only seems to occur when the name of the solution is "www".  With any other solution name the project builds correctly.

As to why one would want a solution named "www", see this post [Ionic and Cordova with Sublime Text 3 + Visual Studio 2013](http://utsavized.com/ionic-and-cordova-with-sublime-text-3-visual-studio-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

You have answered to yourself. The www folder is a reserved name in Cordova projects, so you cannot use it unless you hack Node.js vs-mda code on either side of the build process.